# Haskell, Aeson: Parsing nested JSON with part unnecessary values

Tags: json, parsing, haskell, aeson

I'm a beginner trying to learn more about Haskell and Aeson by parsing some json files I find online.

I have a `.json` that looks like this

```
"Abilities": {
    "Prime": {
          "Ammo": 210,
          "Available": true,
          "Diposition": 3,
          "Type": "Secondary",
          "Class": "Pistols",
          "NormalAttack": {
            "Chance": 0.25,
            "Streak": 2,
            "Rate": 2.67,
            "ShotType": "Hit-Scan",
            "Damage": {
              "Front": 15,
              "Back": 15,
              "Up": 120,
              "Down": 40
            },
              "Status": 0.25
            }
          "Accuracy": 9.8,
          "Reload": 3,
          "Name": "Prime",
          "Magazine": 16,
            },
    "Dual": {
          "Name": "Dual",
          "Available": true,
          "Diposition": 4,
          "Class": "Swords",
          "Type": "Melee",
          "NormalAttack": {
            "Chance": 0.25,
            "Streak": 3,
            "Rate": 1.08,
            "Damage": {
              "Down": 35
            },
              "Status": 0.15
      }
    }
}
```

The file contains some information that I need, but mostly the ones I don't.

This is what I've tried so far

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}

module Lib
    ( someFunc
    ) where

import           Data.Aeson
import           Data.HashMap.Strict as HS
import           Data.Maybe
import           Data.Text
import           Data.Map.Strict
import           GHC.Generics


location = "src/this.json"

someFunc :: IO ()
someFunc = putStrLn "someFunc"



data Abilities = Abilities { abilities :: Map String Ability } deriving (Generic, Show)

instance FromJSON Abilities where
  parseJSON = withObject "Abilities" $
    \v -> Abilities
    <$> v .: pack "Abilities"


data Ability = Ability { ammo         :: Double
                       , normalAttack :: Effect
                       , accuracy     :: Double
                       , name         :: String
                       , diposition   :: Double
                       , reload       :: Double
                       } deriving (Generic, Show)

instance FromJSON Ability where
  parseJSON = withObject "Ability" $
    \v -> Ability
    <$> v .: pack "Ammo"
    <*> v .: pack "NormalAttack"
    <*> v .: pack "Accuracy"
    <*> v .: pack "Name"
    <*> v .: pack "Diposition"
    <*> v .: pack "Reload"


data Effect = Effect { chance :: Double
                     , streak :: Double
                     , rate   :: Double
                     , damage :: Damage
                     , status :: Double
                     } deriving (Generic, Show)

instance FromJSON Effect where
  parseJSON = withObject "Effect" $
    \v -> Effect
    <$> v .: pack "Chance"
    <*> v .: pack "Streak"
    <*> v .: pack "Rate"
    <*> v .: pack "Damage"
    <*> v .: pack "Status"


data Damage = Damage { front :: Double
                     , back  :: Double
                     , up    :: Double
                     , down  :: Double
                     } deriving (Generic, Show)

instance FromJSON Damage where
  parseJSON = withObject "Damage" $
    \v -> Damage
    <$> v .: pack "Front"
    <*> v .: pack "Back"
    <*> v .: pack "Up"
    <*> v .: pack "Down"


main = do
  x <- eitherDecodeFileStrict location :: IO (Either String Abilities)
  print x
```

---

I know of several different ways of parsing the info

1. By parsing the file has `Aeson Value` or `Aeson Object` and applying `Data.HashMap.Strict.toList` to convert it in `[(k, v)]`. The trouble is that on a big file, this method gets really messy.
2. By using several `unConstructor` functions which work like this

`unConstruct (Constructor x) = case (Constructor x) of`
                              `Constructor x -> x`

But same problem: it gets really unreadable and messy really fast.

---

That's why I want to parse the `.json` file as shown in the code above.

---

But the parsing is failing somewhere in the code because I'm getting `Nothing` as an output.

The `.json` file seems to be fine since if I use

```
main = do
  x <- decodeFileStrict location :: IO (Maybe Object)
  print x
```

it works just fine, printing file's contents with appropriate default aeson data types.

---

What could I be doing wrong?

---

Edit: Implemented fix suggested by @danidiaz in the comments.

Error Msg: `Left "Error in $.Abilities['someAbility']: key \"Ammo\" not present"`

Comment: You could construct two data types. One with all the fields, and the one you have. Use Aeson to transform the JSON to the complete data type, then another function to drop the unnecessary fields.

Comment: One problem seems to be that `[Ability]` is parsed using the `FromJSON` instance for lists, which expects an array. But your json has an object instead, with the names of the abilities as the keys.

Comment: Tip: when developing your parser, use `eitherDecodeFileStrict` instead of `decodeFileStrict`. The former gives you an error message than might be useful.

Comment: @mb21 I'm not sure if it'll work. I only know for sure the key, values I need will be in the file. The other ones could be there or the key can be something completely different.

Comment: @danidiaz Thanks for the suggestion. I rewrote the final statement with `eitherDecodeFileStrict` and got `Left "Error in $.Abilities: expected [a], encountered Object"`. Your first assertion was right. How should I fix it? Should I replace `[]` for `Object` type or something else? Maybe a `HashMap`?

Comment: @danidiaz I tried it with `Map String Ability` and got error `Left "Error in $.Abilities['someAbility']: key \"Ammo\" not present"`. Seems like I circled the question and got to the start again

Comment: @atis Should the `Ammo` field be optional? In that case you should declare it as something like `ammo :: Maybe Double` in your datatype, and parse it with `.:?` http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-1.4.2.0/docs/Data-Aeson.html#v:.:-63-

Comment: @atis There is a way of composing `Parser`s with the `<|>` operator (from the `Alternative` typeclass) which means "try this parser, if it fails, try this other parser for the same thing". You could devise a `Parser (Maybe Double)` that returned `Nothing :: Maybe Double` when the text is "NA", and which failed with `fail` otherwise http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:fail Then you could combine it with the other parser to get the full behaviour for that field.

Comment: @danidiaz Sorry I accidentally deleted my previous comment trying to edit it. And thanks for the suggestion! I'll take a look at it!

Comment: do you just need the `Value` of `Prime` object? how about `Dual`?

Comment: @assembly.jc All the objects that fall under `Abilities`

Comment: But `Dual` no `Ammo` , `Accuracy` fields, what value assign to these fields when parses `Dual` object?

Comment: @assembly.jc That's the problem I'm trying to figure out. The necessary value might be there or might not be. As danidiaz suggested, I may need to implement a `Parser (Maybe Double)` where if it encounters a `String` it'll have `Nothing` as a value, otherwise `Just x`

Comment: @danidiaz Could you possibly link some resources on implementing what you described? Looking around I found how to use `<|>` in functions but I'm not sure how to implement something similar when defining a type or how to work it in `v .: "Accuracy"`

Comment: Side note: you can avoid repeatedly typing `pack` by enabling the `OverloadedStrings` extension, which allows you to use string literals as `Text` (or anything with a `GHC.Exts.IsString` instance), i.e., `v .: "Abilities"`. `Data.Text` is meant to be imported `qualified`, like `import Data.Text (Text); import qualified Data.Text as Text` because it exports a lot of names that clash with `Prelude`.