# Haskell: Parsing an object that could be multiple types into one single type

Tags: parsing, haskell, applicative, alternative-functor

I'm a haskell beginner going through aeson, learning more about both by parsing some data files.

Usually when there's a data file, may it be `.json`, a `lua` table, `.csv` format or others, and you want to parse them, there's always a chance of error.

For example, a simple `.json` file like this

```
"root": {
     "m1": {
      "key1": "value1",
      "key2": 2
       },
     "m2": {
       "key1": 1
       },
}
```

Has two oddities: `"m1"` has two subkeys, one has a value in `String` and one in `Int`. `"m2"` has only one subkey, and it has same key as the one above it but the value has a different type ie. `Int`.

---

If it were like this

```
"root": {
     "m1": {
      "key1": "value1",
      "key2": 2
       },
     "m2": {
      "key1": "value1",
      "key2": 2 
       },
}
```

A simple way of parsing it with Aeson would be with these datatypes

```
data Root = Root { Map String Key
                 } deriving (Show, Generic)

data Key = Key { key1 :: String
               , key2 :: Int
               } deriving (Show, Generic)
```

---

If a key was missing

```
"root": {
     "m1": {
      "key1": "value1",
      "key2": 2
       },
     "m2": {
      "key1": "value1"
       },
}
```

This could have done the job

```
data Root = Root { Map String Key
                 } deriving (Show, Generic)

data Key = Key { key1 :: String
               , key2 :: Maybe Int
               } deriving (Show, Generic)
```

---

But what if it were like the first example where not only can the keys not have a value but also have completely different ones.

What if in them you only cared about the numbers or the strings? Would there be a way of parsing them without going out of the type definitions?

Going through some quick searches I found out the Alternative class is just meant for this kind of problems and operator like `*>`, `<>`, `<|>` can prove useful, but I'm not sure how.

I know I need to define a type that can encapsulate all three chances if I just wanted the text or numbers, like

`Data NeededVal = NoValue | TextValue | Needed Int`

or

`Data NeededVal = NoValue | NumericValue | Needed String`

but I'm not sure how I'd go about making them an instance of Applicative & Alternative so that the idea would work out.

This is a short follow-up of my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53466541/haskell-aeson-parsing-nested-json-with-part-unnecessary-values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I try to play with the JSON as below:

```
"root": {
     "m1": {
      "key1": "value1",
      "key2": 2
       },
     "m2": {
       "key1": 1
       },
}
```

and parse it to the follow data types using **[Data.Aeson](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-1.4.1.0/docs/Data-Aeson.html)**:

```
data Root = Root (Map String Key) deriving (Show)

data NeededVal = NoValue | NumericValue | Needed String deriving (Show)

data Key = Key { key1 :: NeededVal , key2 :: NeededVal } deriving (Show)
```

To handle `NoValue`, I use  Alternative `<|>` as

```
instance FromJSON Key where
    parseJSON = withObject "Key" $ \obj -> do
        k1 <- obj .: (pack "key1") <|> pure NoValue
        k2 <- obj .: (pack "key2") <|> pure NoValue
        return(Key k1 k2)
```

To test `String` and `numeric` type, I use `Value` constructor as:

```
instance FromJSON NeededVal where
    parseJSON (String txt) = return $ Needed $ unpack txt
    parseJSON (Number _)   = return $ NumericValue
    parseJSON _            = return NoValue
```

To skip `m1` and `m2` objects and read the `keys` value immediately as:

```
import Data.Map as Map (Map, fromList)
import Data.HashMap.Strict as HM (toList, lookup)
import Data.Aeson.Types (Parser)

parseJSON = withObject "Root" 
                $ \rootObj-> case HM.lookup (pack "root") rootObj of
                                Nothing  -> fail "no Root"
                                Just val -> withObject "Key List" mkRoot val
    where mkRoot obj =
            let (ks, vs) =  unzip $ HM.toList obj
                ks' = map unpack ks
            in  do vs' <- mapM parseJSON vs::Parser [Key]
                   return $ Root $ Map.fromList $ zip ks' vs'
```

and the final result:

```
Right (Root (fromList [
    ("m1",Key {key1 = Needed "value1", key2 = NumericValue}),
    ("m2",Key {key1 = NumericValue, key2 = NoValue})]
))
```

Side notes:

> but I'm not sure how I'd go about making them an instance of
>   Applicative & Alternative so that the idea would work out.

**No**, No need to make them as an instance of `Applicative and Alternative`, the `<|>` operator apply on `Parser` (defined in `Data.Aeson.Types`) not the user defined data type. `Parser` has already be an instance of `Alternative`.

Comment: Thanks for the well thought out answer!